# Iterating a trained network within TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Suppose I have a fully-trained TensorFlow network that converts an input `A` into an output `B`, without any additional inputs. I want to iterate the network to generate a series of states `A,B,C,D,...` where each output is fed as an input to the network in order to generate the next state (like a Markov chain).

Is there a way to do this iteration entirely within TensorFlow (ie, include iteration within the graph) while recording a snapshot of the output at each timestep? This seems to me like it might involve RNN, but I am unsure how to build an RNN when I already have a working network for the forward pass.